# Why does Mrs. Weasley always give Ron maroon clothes?

Tags: harry-potter, ron-weasley

It has been stated a few times by Ron that he HATES the color maroon.

> “Every year she makes us a jumper,’ said Ron, unwrapping his own, ‘and mine’s always maroon.” [...] **"I hate maroon,’** Ron moaned half-heartedly as he pulled it over his head.”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised)</sup></sub>

His mother always either makes his clothes in this color, or buys them in this color. His socks, every Christmas sweater she made Ron was maroon. In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, the dress robes were also maroon (chapter 10):

> He was just piling underwear into his cauldron when Ron
> made a loud noise of disgust behind him.
> “What is that supposed to be?”
> He was holding up something that looked to Harry like a long, maroon velvet dress. It had a moldy-looking lace frill at the collar and matching lace cuffs.
> There was a knock on the door, and Mrs. Weasley entered, carrying an armful of freshly laundered Hogwarts robes.
> “Here you are,” she said, sorting them into two piles. “Now,
> mind you pack them properly so they don’t crease.”
> “Mum, you’ve given me Ginny’s new dress,” said Ron, handing it out to her.
> “Of course I haven’t,” said Mrs. Weasley. “That’s for you. Dress robes.”
> “What?” said Ron, looking horror-struck.
> “Dress robes!” repeated Mrs. Weasley. “It says on your school list that you’re supposed to have dress robes this year . . . robes for formal occasions.”
> “You’ve got to be kidding,” said Ron in disbelief. “I’m not wearing that, no way.”

Why didn't Ron just tell his mom he hates that color? Would he have felt too bad because he knew they didn't have a lot of money, so he accepted what he got then complained to his friends later?

Comment: And some evidence that dress robes were allowed to be in more than one colour?

Comment: Gryffindor colours?

Comment: @DanielRoseman "In some trepidation, Harry opened the last parcel on his camp
bed. It wasn’t as bad as he had expected, however; his dress robes didn’t have any lace on them at all — in fact, they were more or less the same as his school ones, except that **they were bottle green instead of black**."

Comment: @AnthonyGrist *“Every year she makes us a jumper,’ said Ron, unwrapping his own, ‘and mine’s **always** maroon.” - Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised)* *“I hate maroon,’ Ron moaned half-heartedly as he pulled it over his head.” - Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised)*

Answer (score 13):

In Chapter Six of *Philosopher's Stone* we find the following:

> Ron had taken out a lumpy package and unwrapped it. There were four sandwiches inside. He pulled one of them apart and said, “She always forgets I don’t like corned beef.”

Apparently it is not only with regard to clothes that Mrs. Weasley consistently provides Ron with something he doesn't like. Ron specifically attributes the case of the sandwich to Mrs. Weasley forgetting. It is not unreasonable that she would have a hard time keeping track of all seven of her children's preferences. It also seems that Ron has previously told her about his dislike of corned beef, so it is quite possible that he has mentioned his dislike of maroon as well.

Comment: My mother has spent decades carefully buying products with no peanuts in for when I come over. It's my brother who's allergic, not me.

Comment: _Least loved, always, by the mother who craved a daughter…_

Comment: @Valorum She does do the same for your brother, though, right?

Comment: @RyanReich - It's like you've sat in on my therapy sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Every Weasly child had become its "own" color from Miss Weasly. The children are (in order of birth): Bill, Charlie, Percy, Fred & George, Ron, Ginny

Which are the colors come first in ones mind? Red, Yellow, Green and Blue in various order. (From this [page](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/de/wiki/Weihnachten) I know that Percy gets a red one, Fred and George got the same color: a blue one).

So Ron becomes a fifth color... which one should Miss Weasly choose? She is a very practical woman, so she will not choose any expensive modern color. Maroon is a down-to-earth color, you see "no" spots, it is common, so you became patches for it and Miss Weasly is from a generation where maroon was a good color for reasonable people.

This starts as Ron was born and until he is old enough to contradict the tradition is digged into Miss Weaslys mind and she do not (want to?) change it.

Additional the point Alex mentions, Miss Weasly has 7 children and will merge more than favorite colors...

Comment: Do you have any sources that support your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I have the first book in German only. But maybe someone could help me with a citation of the Christmas presents. There will be Percy with a Red jumper and Fred and George with a blue one. The logical next step is to assume that Bill and Charlie has green and yellow jumpers.

Comment: To be fair, I don't see much problem with a German quote. You can bold the colours in it and/or make them a link to leo ("... war **[rot](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/rot)**"). :) Someone can come around and change it to an English one if they find that that's important and they can source one.